# Collapse PHP array elements (not-unique) by value preserving keys

Tags: php, arrays

Ive worked on this so long that I must be over complicating a simple solution.

Given the following in arrays

```
    $in_num = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>1, 'c'=>2, 'd'=>1, 'e'=>2, 'f'=>2, 'g'=>2, 'h'=>2);  
    $in_str = array('a'=>'a', 'b'=>'a', 'c'=>'b', 'd'=>'a', 'e'=>'b', 'f'=>'b', 'g'=>'b);
```

Desired output

```
    $out_num = array('a'=>1, 'c'=>2, 'd'=>1, 'e'=>2);   
    $out_str = array('a'=>'a', 'c'=>'b', 'd'=>'a', 'e'=>'b');
```

The Key order must be maintained.

```
array('a'=>1, 'b'=>'str') does NOT occur.
```

Sure would appreciate your help.

Comment: can't see any other option than a loop, that checks previous value

Comment: array_unique returns 1 or a once, not what I'm looking for. Ive tried loops of many kinds but couldnt get any to work, thats why I'm asking.

Comment: I see it like a collapsable-set. a1 contains b1, d1 and c2 contains void, e2 contains f2 g2 h2

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly

Comment: I should add it is possible as $in=array('a'=>1, 'b'=>1, 'c'=>1, 'd'=>1) which caused several of my attempts to fail. The desired output then would be $out=array('a'=>1)

Comment: answered - works for that array as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want to know and preserve is the key/value pair that differs from the previous value. This can be done with a simple function

```
function collapse($array = array()) {
    //initialize the answer and previous value
    $ans = array();
    $prevValue = null;

    foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
        //we only care if the current $val is different than the previous $value
        if ($val != $prevValue) {
            $ans[$key] = $val;
        }
        //save the current value as the previousValue for the next iteration
        $prevValue = $val;
    }
    return $ans;
}
```

This will return what you are asking when called with `collapse($in_num)` or `collapse($in_str)`.

Comment: This and Dragon answers are the same but since Scott came first he gets the check. Thank you both, my headache is over.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$in_num = array('a'=>1, 'b'=>1, 'c'=>2, 'd'=>1, 'e'=>2, 'f'=>2, 'g'=>2, 'h'=>2);  

$previous = '';
foreach( $in_num as $k=> $v){

  if($v !=$previous){
    $out[$k]=$v;    
  }

$previous=$v;

}

print_r($out);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => 1
    [c] => 2
    [d] => 1
    [e] => 2
)
```